# xargs I already have full command set

Tags: shell, xargs

I have a file like this.

```
rm a.txt
mkdir foo
cp a.doc docs
```

I am used to xargs but following command is not doing anything.

```
cat commands.txt | xargs -l1
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: Another solution is: cat commands.txt | xargs -L 1 | sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it wrong! if your file is all shell commands, treat it as a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm a.txt
mkdir foo
cp a.doc docs
```

then on command line , `chmod u+x commands.txt`

```
./commands.txt
```

the "defacto" naming convention for shell script ends with extension `.sh`, although it can be anything. So try to name your script as ".sh" extension

Answer (score 0):

Erm :

> $ mv commands.txt commands.sh
>
> $ chmod +x command.sh
>
> $ ./command.sh

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to make it executable, source it in your current shell:

bash/ksh/...: `. commands.txt`

csh/...: `source commands.txt`

Answer (score -1):

If you commands are not in a file but the output from a program you may do use GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/:

```
cat commands.txt | parallel -j1
```

If the commands can be run in parallel (i.e. do not depend on eachother to complete) you can even do:

```
cat commands.txt | parallel
```